# Reading a txt file from Javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

am trying to read few lines from a txt file using JS,and i have this code but its not working for some reason,,

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 

var s = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\wamp\\www\\22.txt", 1, true);

var row = s.ReadLine();


alert(row);
```

any suggestions?!

Comment: When you say not working.. what is not working? Are you testing this in IE or any other browser?

Comment: i tried firefox and chrome and yeah no output!

Comment: Most browsers won't allow that. you could run the script from the console, and it would work. But not within a browser, unless the page itself is loaded with high trust. In IE there are security zones you can set for this; not sure about the other browsers.

Comment: You could install a web server and then use `XMLHttpRequest`. Working locally has its disadvantages.

Comment: The above will only work out of the box if you save the code with extension .HTA for html application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running WAMP anyway, just use standard AJAX to fetch the file 22.txt from the server. The easiest way is to use jQuery, where the code would be:

```
$.get("22.txt", function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

You can search for how to do this without jQuery if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your browser has the right permissions to perform that kind of operation. Usually, browsers won't allow direct file system access by default.

Comment: am nt sure about that, coz i tried it in PHP and it read the file,

Comment: PHP is server side. JavaScript is client side. Big difference.

Answer (score 2):

Only IE supports `ActiveXObject`.  Trying to use `ActiveXObject` on any other browser will fail because there is no such variable defined.

You need to either limit yourself to IE, write a browser plugin instead, or give up trying to get file system access on other browsers and proxy files through a server instead.

Comment: This generally won't work from IE either, as the object in question is not marked Safe-For-Scripting.