# Reading TXT file only with javascript

Tags: javascript

It is possible to read line by line txt file from my HTML5 game resources? (Resources = one of folders in my game project)
I keep in this file informations about levels in my game.
I found only examples using PHP, Ajax, but all of this requires server, but I want to run my game on servers or offline mode.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always use ajax to request the files you need, if you are not using a webserver, you could try using the file:// url scheme. (or use an iframe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a txt file from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135610/reading-a-txt-file-from-javascript)

Comment: You can go with appcache. The first time the file will be downloaded form your server. But the next time, if the client is offline, it will be retrieved from the local cache. http://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Try using local storage instead of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique used often by templates and preprocessing languages (like LESS or CoffeeScript) is to use a script tag with a `type` attribute not recognized by browsers.  This causes it to be ignored by the browser and search engines, but be accessible by JavaScript.

## [demo](http://jsbin.com/ofapuw/3/) | [code view](http://jsbin.com/ofapuw/3/edit)

```
  <script type="text/mygamelevel" id="level1">
    0010011001111011
    0011011100010
    10101110111101101
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var level = document.getElementById("level1").text;
    var lines = level.split("\n");
    for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
      var line = lines[i];
      if (!line.trim()) continue;

      alert(line);
    }
  </script>
```

---

If a file is preferred, you can dynamically request it.  This is an example using [jQuery's get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function.

```
$.get('levels/level1.txt', function(level) {
    var lines = level.split("\n");
    for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
      var line = lines[i];
      if (!line.trim()) continue;

      alert(line);
    }
});
```

No guarantee is made that the code in the callback will be executed at any given time, so I suggest putting some start-new-level code in there, as opposed to anywhere else in the code.  Otherwise, you don't know if you have the level information downloaded yet or not.  This problem is averted by inlining the data as shown in the first snippet of this answer.

Comment: Instead of `.innerHTML` use `.text`, [it's a valid attribute on every inline script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12761170/1139697).

Comment: Thanks @Zeta, I didn't think it was correct, but it was working :-)

Comment: Thanks, but levels is a bit much and I don't want to keep all in main index.html file ^^ Can I do this like that?  <script id="level1" src="levels/level1.txt"></script> This isn't work, so what should I do to make it correct?

Comment: @Ludwik11, I added an example of asynchronously getting level information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Browser's JavaScript do not, and should not, have direct access to local file system.