# how get list of files in a folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-c++-2010-express

I am working on project for desktop application. I am using [Qt](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://qt.digia.com/&ei=bCeXUtCHHY2JrgfmsoGIDg&usg=AFQjCNGEUWK4vJ7UIstsr0y4skLWR5MtMA&sig2=-24GuUCrukWeGJZxOWboQg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bmk) controls with visual c++.
I am loading an html file in the QWebView as,

```
m_pWebView->load(QUrl("../../../demo/index_Splash_Screen.html"));
```

Now, what i want is, say, I have some `.zip` files in my location "c:\demo", I want list (or array of file names) of the files present in that directory.

How can i do this through javascript ?

**PS:** I went through this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), but it didnt match my requirement. I have not worked with of html, javascript and jquery. Please help me.

Comment: Dont think u can.. but a solution is to create a service ( for example REST) that returns the filelist in the folder you want, and than call the service with jquery..

Comment: Did any one have experience working with Qt controls ? Will Qt control `QWebView` work as expected, using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2019/Find-files-with-JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot access local files or directories using javascript due to security issues.

Edit: I hadn't thought about the file api so thought for a moment this might not be true, but without some user input to give permission, this still cannot be done.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251432/read-a-local-file-using-javascript-html5-file-api-offline-website) has a good response from PhilNicholas:

> I'm afraid I may be the bearer of bad news for your design: The action
>   you are requesting expressly violates the security model as specified
>   in the File API spec. The client implementation of FileReader() must
>   make sure that "all files that are being read by FileReader objects
>   have first been selected by the user." (W3C File API , 13. Security
>   Considerations: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#security-discussion).
>
> It would be a huge security risk of browser scripts could just
>   arbitrarily open and read any file from a path without any user
>   interaction. No browser manufacturer would allow unfettered access to
>   the entire file system like that.

Thinking about it however, if it is all being run locally, you could use ajax to query a server side script that could return the directory you request.

Comment: Do you know if Qt control `QWebView` work as expected, using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2019/Find-files-with-JavaScript ?

Comment: I couldn't really comment on that unfortunately, but as Qt is cross-platform oriented, my guess would be the underlying rendering engine is probably Webkit. In which case I doubt it will work as according to that link, "your browser should have access to run ActiveX objects", and I think that's beyond Webkit's capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But i wonder, that IT industry is growing so fast, still we are facing the problems that doesn't have solutions...:(

Comment: In some ways I hope this is a problem that doesn't get solved. The thought of javascript on any website being able to access my files without permission is a scary one. Maybe you could have a look at WebSocket in HTML5, potentially you could have your desktop application serve file directory requests to the WebSocket? An ugly solution I know, but they all are for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Windows application then you could access the local filesystem by using ActiveX objects. You might have a look at this link [Reading a txt file from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135610/reading-a-txt-file-from-javascript)

Note that activeX usage is possible only when using IE as browser/engine; I used to need it a while ago for developing an HTML application (.hta files).